# How to query data to see how many connection a single row has?

Tags: t-sql

I have the tables below where a Course consist of many events. I would like to know how many events does a particular Course has.

The **SQL Server is 2014.**

```
COURSE 
| ID | NAME    |
| 1  | Course 1|

COURSE_EVENT
| ID | COURSE_ID | EVENT_NAME   |
| 1  | 1         | Introduction to Javascript |
| 2  | 1         | Introduction to Angularjs |
| 3  | 1         | Introduction to Angularjs2 |
```

I have the query below:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  COURSE_EVENT
WHERE 
  COURSE_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM COURSE)
```

But it returns only one row. What I would like to see is the following:

```
| COURSE_ID | EVENT_AMOUNT |
|1          | 3            |
```

I'm kind of noob in SQL. Before I put together a foreach (I feel it would be overengineering) I ask the community.

Comment: The words you are looking for are `GROUP BY`. Read this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/75779/. Heck, read the whole series.

Comment: @sayusiando, check my post to resolve your query..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT C.NAME, COUNT(CE.ID)
FROM COURSE C INNER JOIN COURSE_EVENT CE
ON C.ID = CE.COURSE_ID
GROUP BY C.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is a FK then ID must be in course

```
SELECT COURSE_ID, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM COURSE_EVENT
GROUP BY COURSE_ID
```